# Xcode 4.2 and IOS SDK 5 beta6, the behavior "Run generates output" not working, is this a bug?

Tags: xcode4, behavior

I set this behavior to show the console.
But this behavior is never triggered now.(I have some NSLog in my app)
It works for some versions before, but now it just don't work like before.

Is this some intended change or just a bug?